# Boost issue building Litecoin on MacOS 10.12.6

Tags: c++, macos, boost, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have pulled Litecoin from master branch and when i try to build on OSX i get the error:

```
CXXLD litecoind
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_for(timespec const&)", referenced from:
MilliSleep(long long) in libbitcoin_util.a(libbitcoin_util_a-utiltime.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [litecoind] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Boost version installed is 1.65.1 via Homebrew
in location:
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/

Litecoin Core: 0.13.99
I have tried uninstalling boost and building from source as mentioned here:
https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/issues/170

and i get the same error.
I have made sure all the dependancies required are installed but seems to be a boost issue somewhere.

A fresh pull from master and ./autogen.sh - ./configure - make produces this log:

https://pastebin.com/byUg2msu

Comment: have you mentioned this on the boost.org mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a linker error, i uninstalled boost, reinstalled it and then

`brew link boost --force`

worked fine after that